# Spinnaker not showing automatically triggered executions

Tags: spinnaker

I have several pipelines in Spinnaker with automated triggers. However, I'm not seeing the executions for the ones under the Pipelines tab. I sometimes manually trigger a redeployment not knowing that the specified version is out there.

Is there some option to show these?

Comment: No execution = no trigger occurred. Could you provide more details? What kind of trigger? Are there any related tasks? Have you checked orca logs?

Comment: 1. Since there is little information i would suggest you add the version number of spinnaker you are currently using 2. are you deploying and using which particular Cloud Provider? 3. please share your halconfig! 4. Are you running Spinnaker as a Kubernetes deployment or localdebian 5. Please upgrade your spinnaker version to the latest stable version 6. Is the error still being displayed?? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Orca stores data in Redis if something reboots and somehow relates to Redis then you lose track of your valuable execution history.

You must enable persistence in Orca for your Spinnaker deployment. I will attach the document required. My suggestion is to go with a cloud provider that supports MySQL 5.7 or MariaDB.

My deployment points to MariaDB and is fine. Default settings are enough and satisfy most complex requirements.

[Spinnaker Set up Orca to use SQL](https://spinnaker.io/setup/productionize/persistence/orca-sql/)